Averaging the expectations of stationary sequences
Consider the Hilbert space
$$
\ell^2 :=\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}) = \left\{ a = (a_k)_{ k \in \mathbb{Z}} : \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } a_k^2 < \infty \right\}, \quad \langle a, b \rangle := \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } \langle a_k, b_k \rangle, \quad \lVert a  \rVert = \sqrt{ \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } a_k^2 }
$$
and its weghted counterpart
$$
\ell^2_w :=\ell^2_w(\mathbb{Z}) = \left\{ (a_k)_{ k \in \mathbb{Z}} : \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } w_k a_k^2 < \infty \right\}, \quad \langle a, b \rangle_w := \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } w_k \langle a_k, b_k \rangle, \quad \lVert a  \rVert_w = \sqrt{ \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } w_k a_k^2 }
$$
where the weights $w = ( w_k )_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} }$ are given as
$$
w_k = \frac{1}{2^{|k|}}, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
For every $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ we now define a translation mapping $T_l$ such that
$$
T_l ( ( a )_{ k \in \mathbb{Z }} ) = ( a_{ k + l} )_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} }.
$$
It is then easy to see that for any $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ and any sequence $a$ in $\ell^2$ or $\ell^2_w$, the translated sequence $T_l a$ is again, respectively, in $\ell^2$ or $\ell^2_w$.
Now let $X = ( X_k )_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} }$ and $Y = ( Y_k )_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} }$ be random variables on some probability space $( \Omega, \mathbb{P}, \mathcal{F})$ with values in $\ell^2_w$. Moreover, assume that that $X$ and $Y$ have stationary distributions, in the sense that
$$
T_l X \overset{d}{=} X, \quad T_l Y \overset{d}{=} Y, \quad \forall l \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

I am interested in estimating the expression
$$
\liminf_{ n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{( 2n + 1 )} \sum_{ l \in [ -n, n ] \cap \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{E} \lVert T_l X - T_l Y \rVert_{w}^2, \tag{1}
$$
with
$$
\mathbb{E} \lVert X - Y \rVert_{w}^2. \tag{2}
$$

We can see that
$$
\mathbb{E} \lVert T_l X - T_l Y \rVert_{w}^2 = \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } w_k | X_{ k + l } - Y_{ k + l} |^2 \right] = \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } w_k \mathbb{E} | X_{ k + l } - Y_{ k + l} |^2
$$
Two observations can then be made:

If all the weights $w_k$ were set to $1$, so that $\ell^2_w = \ell^2$, then
$$
\sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } w_k \mathbb{E} | X_{ k + l } - Y_{ k + l} |^2 = \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{E} | X_{ k + l } - Y_{ k + l} |^2 = \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{E} | X_k - Y_k |^2 = \mathbb{E} \lVert X - Y \rVert^2,
$$
in which case the expression in $(1)$ is exactly $\mathbb{E} \lVert X - Y \rVert^2$.

If the weights are kept as before, but it is additionally assumed that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly stationary, then
$$
\sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } w_k \mathbb{E} | X_{ k + l } - Y_{ k + l} |^2 = \sum_{ k \in \mathbb{Z} } w_k \mathbb{E} | X_k - Y_k |^2 = \mathbb{E} \lVert X - Y \rVert_w^2,
$$
in which case the expression in $(1)$ is exactly $\mathbb{E} \lVert X - Y \rVert_w^2$.


But how can $(1)$ be estimated with $(2)$ without the assumptions made in the observations?
